# ngx-bootstrap popover is not working properly

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using [ngx-bootstrap popover](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover). I want the popover should open on hover, and all opened ones should be closed if new one is opened.

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-ajba3s?file=app/four-directions.html)

As per requirement I want above sample should controlled by parent component and target popover lies in child component. I need this for modularity requirement

<del>[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-rxhwgm?file=app%2Ffour-directions.ts) *ngFor in child component html*</del>  this is wrong demo

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-rwjrel?file=app/four-directions.html)  *ngFor in parent component html*

parent component

```
export class DemoPopoverFourDirectionsComponent  implements 

AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChildren(PopoverDirective) popovers: QueryList<PopoverDirective>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.popovers.forEach((popover: PopoverDirective) => {
      popover.onShown.subscribe(() => {
        this.popovers
        .filter(p => p !== popover)
        .forEach(p => p.hide());
      });
    });
  }

varArr=[1,2,3,4]

}
```

**In popover there are  buttons which need to be clicked. If I use triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" I cannot click  buttons inside the popover**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change your code and I hope it's what you needed

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-v4s9eh?file=app%2Ffour-directions.ts)

**UPDATE**:

[here is the final code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-v4s9eh?file=app%2Ffour-directions.ts)

Comment: Thanks you code is working in demo/sample program, But in my actual case it does not works. Difference is child component gets data from the API and there is some sort of delay. this might be the reason.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.popovers.forEach((popover: PopoverDirective) => {
      popover.onShown.subscribe(() => {
        this.popovers
        .filter(p => p !== popover)
        .forEach(p => p.hide());
        console.log(popover)  //demo shows in demo, but in my actual code it doesn't
      });
    });
  }`

Comment: move the this.popovers.foreach... right after  this.popovers=(items); maybe this will fix it

Comment: thanks for the help console is showing logs, but not working, angular version is 6.1.10 and ngx-bootstrap version is 3.3.0. Do this variation is causing problem

Comment: no, the problem is not related.try adding  this.onFinish.emit(this.popovers); in your child component after you read data from server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191888/discussion-between-patata-and-ehsan-kiani).

Comment: Thanks your final solutions works, please update your post so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"`

See: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#triggers

**Update:**

Because of new requirements here is a changed version which closes an old popover and let us click a button inside:

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor="let d of varArr; let i = index">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary"      
          #pop="bs-popover"
          [popover]="popover"
          popoverTitle="Popover on top"          
          placement="right" triggers="mouseenter"          
          (onShown)="closeOldPopover(pop)"
          [outsideClick]="true">
    Popover on top
  </button>

  <ng-template #popover>
    <button (click)="pop.hide()">Test</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

**TS**

```js
private _currentPopover: any;

@Input() varArr;

ngOnInit() {

}

public closeOldPopover(popover: any): void {
  if (this._currentPopover && this._currentPopover !== popover) {
    this._currentPopover.hide();
  }

  this._currentPopover = popover;
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't solve the requirement. I apologise for less information. In popover there are some buttons which need to be clicked. If I use `triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"` i cannot click the buttons inside the popover

Comment: Okay that's a new requirement. Then replace mouseleave with click and play a bit with autoClose ('inside', 'outside', true, false). I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: its ngx-bootstrap not ng-bootstrap

Comment: @Patata My fault with ngx-bootstrap, but now it's correct. The updated solution should work for you.

Comment: thanks for the update, but as I mentioned in question `As per requirement I want above sample should controlled by parent component and target popover lies in child component. I need this for modularity requirement`. Hiding logic is done in child component and I need to be done in parent component